# How can I run multiple PowerShell commands with restarts in userdata?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, active-directory, terraform

I am looking to spin up a Domain Controller in AWS using Terraform. I've tried passing all commands through userdata, but I just can't find a way to get the commands run after a reboot.

Here is my userdata:

```
    workflow Rename-And-Continue {
    Rename-Computer -NewName "HACKDC" -Force -Passthru
    Restart-Computer -Wait

    Install-WindowsFeature AD-Domain-Services, rsat-adds -IncludeAllSubFeature
    Install-ADDSForest -DomainName hackdc -SafeModeAdministratorPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "SOMEPASSWORD" -AsPlainText -Force) -DomainMode Win2012R2 -DomainNetbiosName HACKDC -ForestMode Win2012R2 -Confirm:$false -Force
    Restart-Service NetLogon -EA 0
    Get-Service -Name ADWS; while($s.Status -ne "Running") {Start-Service ADWS; Start-Sleep 3};

}

$AtStartup = New-JobTrigger -AtStartup
Register-ScheduledJob -Name testWorkflow -Trigger $AtStartup -ScriptBlock {Import-Module PSWorkflow; Get-Job testWorkflow -State Suspended | Resume-Job};
Rename-And-Continue -AsJob -JobName testWorkflow
```

The main question here is what can be done to ensure that the workflow properly runs, so that I can set up the environment even if multiple restarts are required (yes I know the above isn't every step for properly configuring a DC, just a snippet)

Comment: Would you be opposed to setting up a Powershell DSC Pull server? I think this would be the cleanest and most extensible solution. However, I think it can be done using a single script, see https://deploymentmechanic.wordpress.com/2017/04/15/weekend-learning-day-2-resume-windows-server-configuration-after-restart-using-userdata-in-aws-using-powershell/ which sets a Run Count in the registry and uses a switch() to execute the required phase per reboot.

Comment: That could potentially work.  Was hoping to be able to leverage just a combination of Terraform and Userdata, but it doesn't look likely

Comment: Userdata executed by AWS is just on first run. Technically the underlying thing under userdata on Linux systems (cloud-init) allows for things on each restart but AWS userdata doesn't populate that part and that wouldn't help you on Linux. If this was a Linux system then I'd have the command as an enabled one shot service that would then run on each startup but I don't know what the equivalent is in Windows.

Comment: A bit of a hack method would be to have it create scheduled task in Windows that is set to run on startup. However your script tied to that scheduled task would need logic to make sure it does not repeat a step (maybe some log file on the system that writes "last step" it performed.

Comment: I used Task Scheduler to run PowerShell scripts to let me know when a server had bounced. I would set something up so when the server restarts it will run the script you need it to run. I can go into details if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Your current script only waits for the computer to restart.

```
-Wait <SwitchParameter>
        Indicates that this cmdlet suppresses the Windows PowerShell prompt and blocks the pipeline 
        until all of the computers have restarted. You can use this parameter in a script to restart
        computers and then continue to process when the restart is finished.
```

In order to continue running the script, you may want to use the following.

```
# This will restart the computer. Then delay 2 seconds. 
# Then wait for PowerShell to become available again. 
# It will also timeout after 300 seconds (5 mins).
Restart-Computer -Wait -For PowerShell -Timeout 300 -Delay 2
```

For more information just use the Get-Help cmdlet with the -Examples flag. The specific example would be the one below.

```
PS C:\>Restart-Computer -ComputerName "Server01" -Wait -For PowerShell -Timeout 300 -Delay 2

    This command restarts the Server01 remote computer and then waits up to 5 minutes (300 seconds) 
    for Windows PowerShell to be available on the restarted computer before it continues.
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html#user-data-scripts-subsequent

Userdata for EC2 runs only for initial launch by default.  Look at the link above to get the config edit to change this.  Mind that your UserData will now need to learn what step it is on each time it runs or it will just run the first commands repeatedly (rename instance, reboot).  It needs to either leave it's state behind in the instance via logging or something or it needs to CHECK steps before re-running them.